# Get <td> using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the table down, clicking on the displayed line I want to get the values, and perform an action, hide the other lines and display content related to the executed line. For example, when clicking on the line, display a link and an image related to the selected line. How to do this using JQuery?

---

```
</head>
<body>

<h1>Pesquisa cidade</h1>

<form name="formulario_busca" method="post"/>
    <input type="text" name="nome_cidade"/>
    <input type="submit" name="busca"/>
</form>

<?php

$busca = $_POST['nome_cidade'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE cidade LIKE '%".$busca."%'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
mysqli_fetch_array($resultado,$lista_Cidades);
?>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered"> 

<?php
if ((mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0) && ($busca != "") ):
    while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) { 

?>
<tr>
    <td id="linha"><?= $linha['cidade']. ' - ' .$linha['regiao']. ' - ' .$linha['subregiao'] ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
    } echo "<br/>";
endif;  if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)<=0):
        echo "Cidade não encontrada";
        endif;
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Attach event to `td` then make use of `$(this)` to do what you need to do.

Comment: There is no jQuery / javascript here. And what does php have to do with it? If your question is about jQuery / javascript, you should post the html and the javascript.

Comment: "Here's some php code, do my javascript for me thanks"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<script>

function clickCell() {

$('.table td').hide();
$(this).show();

}

</script>
```

And on the td:

```
<td onclick="clickCell()"></td>
```

Comment: It worked to hide the lines, but my goal now is to use the data of the clicked line, selecting the data of the line and displaying it next to an image, on the same page.

It's possible?

Answer (score 1):

1- You should NOT use the same ID for all the TDs you have there, you can replace it by a class if you're using it for styling.

2- for getting the value using jQUery you can do, per example the text inside the TD:

```
$('table > td').on('click',function(){
  var x = $(this).text();
  //and show the value of x here...using a model or whatever you want.
});
```

Comment: Using:

var x = $ (this) .text ();

I'm going to get a whole row and store it as string in var x? Is there a way to get one of the <td> data, such as 'Region'? That way I can store it somewhere else and use the information for other things on the page.